# O que significam as seguintes medidas das colunas/linhas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Na criação de linhas ou colunas do WPF, o que significa cada uma destas medidas?

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

- `50` — essa sei que é uma medida fixa.
- `50*`
- `*`
- `Auto`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O asterisco indica que o tamanho deve ser proporcional. O cálculo é baseado em todos os valores encontrados em todos os asteriscos daquele grupo de elementos.

De uma certa forma é o jeito de usar porcentagem indiretamente. 100% é a soma de todos os números do grupo e aí se proporcionaliza a porcentagem de cada um de acordo com seu valor individual. Algumas pessoas gostam de garantir que a soma sempre resulte em 100, o que equivale à porcentagem.

Quando tem elementos de tamanho fixo - e considere que o `Auto` tem tamanho fixo, esse espaço é usado de forma independente. Só os asteriscos são considerados nessa contagem.

- `50*` - aqui está usando 50 unidades (não importa que unidade é, é só um número)
- `*` - quando não usa um número é o mesmo que usar 1
- `Auto` - o tamanho será ajustável de acordo com o que tiver no elemento, ele pode ir variando se o "dado" interno dele variar

Nesse exemplo o primeiro elemento terá 50 unidades e o último só se saberá de acordo com dado dentro dele. Se sabe que o segundo elemento será 50 vezes maior que o terceiro elemento. Então dentro do espaço que sobrar para esses dois elementos mais de 98% será ocupado pelo segundo elemento e menos de 2% será ocupado pelo terceiro.

Lembre-se que o WPF não trabalha com quantidade fixa de pontos, ela é calculada de acordo com a necessidade. Essa unidade usada é totalmente virtual.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).